# Syntax Error in stored procedure call

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
EXEC dbo.Alpha @BatchName = 'Test',@BatchNumber = '2',@Profile = 'SQLTEST'
```

This is giving me an error

> incorrect syntax near ','

I've tried removing or adding every comma. SQL Server 2008 Express and Management Studio.

Here is the procedure for reference:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Alpha 
    @BatchName NVARCHAR(50),
    @BatchNumber NVARCHAR(50),
    @Profile NVARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Batch_Reports NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @Batch_Reports = @BatchName + '_' + @BatchNumber + '_reports'

    DECLARE @Memory TABLE (docNumber NVARCHAR(50),SortOrder NVARCHAR(50));

    DECLARE @Thought NVARCHAR(1000)
    SET @Thought = 'INSERT INTO Memory (docNumber,SortOrder)
                    SELECT (docNumber,SortOrder) FROM dbo.' + @Batch_Reports

    EXEC (@Thought)

    DECLARE @GoldFish NVARCHAR(50)

    DECLARE lost CURSOR FOR 
         SELECT DISTINCT docNumber 
         FROM @Memory

    OPEN lost
    FETCH NEXT FROM lost INTO @GoldFish

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT BatchIndexing.DocumentIndexID 
                       FROM BatchIndexing 
                       WHERE BatchIndexing.docNumber = @GoldFish 
                         AND BatchIndexing.BatchName = @BatchName + ' ' + @BatchNumber)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO BatchIndexing (BatchName, docNumber, ProfileUsed, TotalPages)
            VALUES (@BatchName + ' ' + @BatchNumber, @GoldFish, @Profile, '0');

            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [DocumentIndexID]

            DECLARE @Identity NVARCHAR(50)
            SET @Identity = (SELECT DocumentIndexID 
                             FROM BatchIndexing 
                             WHERE BatchIndexing.docNumber = @GoldFish 
                               AND BatchIndexing.BatchName = @BatchName + ' ' + @BatchNumber)

            INSERT INTO IndexingFields (DocumentIndexID, FieldName, FieldValue)
            VALUES(@Identity, 'Barcode', (NULL))

            INSERT INTO IndexingFields (DocumentIndexID, FieldName, FieldValue)
            VALUES (@Identity, 'Docket #', (NULL))

            INSERT INTO IndexingFields (DocumentIndexID, FieldName, FieldValue)
            VALUES (@Identity, 'Respondent Name', (NULL))
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            FETCH NEXT FROM lost INTO @GoldFish
        END         
    END

    DECLARE @Omega TABLE (DocumentIndexID NVARCHAR(50),
                          BatchName NVARCHAR(50),
                          docNumber NVARCHAR(50),
                          ProfileUsed NVARCHAR(50),
                          TotalPages NVARCHAR(50),
                          SortOrder NVARCHAR(50)
                         );

    SELECT
       [BI].[DocumentIndexID],
       [BI].[BatchName],
       [BI].[docNumber],
       [BI].[ProfileUsed],
       [AR].[SortOrder]
    FROM 
       BatchIndexing BI
    INNER JOIN 
       @Memory AR ON [BI].[docNumber] = [AR].[docNumber]
    WHERE 
       [BI].[BatchName] = @BatchName + ' ' + @BatchNumber
    ORDER BY 
       [AR].[SortOrder] ASC

    DECLARE @Heather NVARCHAR(50)

    DECLARE found CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT DISTINCT SortOrder 
        FROM @Omega

    OPEN found
    FETCH NEXT FROM found INTO @Heather

    DECLARE @I NVARCHAR(50)
    SET @I = (SELECT DocumentIndexID FROM @Omega WHERE SortOrder = '1')

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Spawn NVARCHAR(50)
        SET @Spawn = (SELECT IndexingFields.FieldValue FROM IndexingFields
            WHERE IndexingFields.FieldName = 'Docket #' AND IndexingFields.DocumentIndexID = (SELECT DocumentIndexID FROM @Omega
            WHERE SortOrder = @Heather))
        IF @Spawn IS NULL
            BEGIN
                UPDATE IndexingFields
                SET FieldValue = (SELECT FieldValue FROM IndexingFields WHERE DocumentIndexID = @I AND FieldName = 'Docket #')
                WHERE DocumentIndexID = (SELECT DocumentIndexID FROM @Omega WHERE SortOrder = @Heather)
                AND FieldName = 'Docket #';
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @I = (SELECT DocumentIndexID FROM @Omega WHERE SortOrder = @Heather)
                FETCH NEXT FROM found INTO @Heather
            END
    END

    DECLARE @Dori NVARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE favor CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINcT SortOrder FROM @Omega
    OPEN favor
    FETCH NEXT FROM favor INTO @Dori
    SET @I = (SELECT DocumentIndexID FROM @Omega WHERE SortOrder = '1')

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Spawn = (SELECT FieldValue FROM IndexingFields
            WHERE IndexingFields.FieldName = 'Barcode' AND IndexingFields.DocumentIndexID = (SELECT DocumentIndexID FROM @Omega
            WHERE SortOrder = @Heather))
        IF @Spawn IS NULL
            BEGIN
                UPDATE IndexingFields
                SET FieldValue = (SELECT FieldValue FROM IndexingFields WHERE DocumentIndexID = @I AND FieldName = 'Barcode')
                WHERE DocumentIndexID = (SELECT DocumentIndexID FROM @Omega WHERE SortOrder = @Dori)
                AND FieldName = 'Barcode'
                DECLARE @Administrator NVARCHAR(50)
                SET @Administrator = 'UPDATE ' + @Batch_Reports + ' SET IsIndexed = 1 
                                     WHERE docNumber = Omega.docNumber 
                                     AND Omega.SortOrder = ' + @Heather
                EXEC (@Administrator)

                DECLARE @Transporter NVARCHAR(50)
                SET @Transporter = 'UPDATE Batches SET CurrentModule = QC Index 
                                     WHERE BatchName = ' + @BatchName + ' ' + @BatchNumber
                EXEC (@Transporter)

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @I = (SELECT DocumentIndexID FROM @Omega WHERE SortOrder = @Dori)
                FETCH NEXT FROM found INTO @Heather
            END
    END
END
GO
```

This is a small project for work I've been kicking around. I know there are going to be a ton of other/better ways to do this. While that input is appreciated I'm really more interested in making do what I want it to do. Which is essentially set all the empty fields to the last field that wasn't empty.

Comment: Interesting variable names!

Comment: Thanks. Which in particular did you like?

Comment: Try putting a semicolon at the end and making sure that this is the only line being executed.

Comment: Goldfish and Spawn in particular. What line number does the error occur on?

Comment: Your dynamic sql select shouldn't have brackets round the column list. `select (docNumber,SortOrder)`

Comment: Semicolon at the end makes no difference. Error reads line 2. Martin you'll have to be more specific about the column list.

Comment: My comment is already pretty specific. You might need to refresh the page if you are looking at the pre edit version.

Comment: I was looking at the pre-edit version when I replied. That fixed this error Martin. And Goldfish because it only remembers it while it's happening then it's gone. Spawn because there are going to be about 90 original documents that get split into about 1300 and I need the indexing information to be copied from the original to the spawn.

Comment: Now I'm getting an "invalid object name Memory".

Comment: There's a line "SET @ Thought = 'INSERT INTO Memory..." that most probably causes the issue. a side note: Please note that a table variable can't be used together with dynamic SQL the way you're trying to use it. The dynamic SQL will be executed in a separate scope . Therefore, it cannot "see" the @memory table, nor can this table be used to insert data by using dynamic sql.

Comment: Yup. That was it. Changed to a local temp table and it's working now.